# Replace the text file without making it empty

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node js , I want to replace the contents of text file without making it empty even for fraction of seconds.

For example below line of code runs every second and keep replacing the text file

```
jsonprice = JSON.stringify(ltparr);
         if(ltparr.length>0)
         {
         fs.writeFile('/var/www/test.txt', jsonprice, function (err) {
         });
```

But some times for 1 or 2 seconds text.txt file is empty , So i tried below code to make sure to update only if there is something .

```
try {
         jsonprice = JSON.stringify(ltparr);
         if(ltparr.length>0)
         {
         fs.writeFile('/var/www/test.txt', jsonprice, function (err) {
         }); 
         }
 
    } catch(e) {
    }
```

But still for out of 100 requests , 1 or two times test.txt is empty.How do i prevent this to make sure test.txt is never empty.Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain why to do this? It's a strange need.

Comment: did you mean `if(jsonprice.length>0)` since that's the thing your write?

Comment: my ltparr ir array am just making sure it has some array items

Comment: I'm not sure the filesystem allows for rewriting a file with 100% availability.

Comment: Some workarounds would be - code in a failsafe where you read test.txt, have it delay a bit and try again if it is empty. Or avoid using the filesystem altogether - If you are serving test.txt as a webserver, use node.js to create a http response programmatically. Or you could store the data in a database

Comment: hi , is update in database faster than writing text files.. I wanto update this text column every seconds

Comment: @Graciewilliams, I don't think the database is faster than writing a file because the database engine itself relies on the file system.